# IllegalStateException after creating AlertDialog API 19

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-4.4-kitkat, illegalstateexception

yesterday one of our customers reported that our app crashes on his Xperia Z1 with Android 4.4.2. After testing in an avd, we found out, that this exception doesn't happen on API 18 or earlier. The app crashes after the Dialog is returned but the reason seems to be the `AlertDialog.setView` because if we remove this line, the app doesn't crash.

I already spent quite some time searching the web for a solution and trying different approaches but didn't find anything that's helping me.

Are there any known problems with API 19 and `AlertDialog.setView`? Are we doing something wrong? Does someone have an idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Dirk

This is the (simplified, but still crashing) code i'm creating the dialog with:

```
AlertDialog alert = null;
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            ...
        });

builder.setNeutralButton(
        getResources().getString(R.string.text_button_help),
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            ...
        });

builder.setView(this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.timeline,
        null));

alert = builder.create();
return alert;
```

And the LogCat output:

```
06-11 06:44:25.710: E/ViewRootImpl(1188): Attempting to destroy the window while drawing!
06-11 06:44:25.710: E/ViewRootImpl(1188):   window=android.view.ViewRootImpl@b237f958, title=foo/bar
06-11 06:44:25.820: W/dalvikvm(1188): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a3aba8)
06-11 06:44:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1188): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 06:44:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1188): Process: foo, PID: 1188
06-11 06:44:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1188): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Surface has already been released.
06-11 06:44:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.view.Surface.checkNotReleasedLocked(Surface.java:408)
06-11 06:44:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.view.Surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(Surface.java:261)
06-11 06:44:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2507)
06-11 06:44:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2409)
06-11 06:44:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2253)
06-11 06:44:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1883)
06-11 06:44:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
06-11 06:44:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
06-11 06:44:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
06-11 06:44:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
06-11 06:44:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
06-11 06:44:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
06-11 06:44:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-11 06:44:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-11 06:44:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-11 06:44:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-11 06:44:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 06:44:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-11 06:44:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-11 06:44:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-11 06:44:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: hi pplease have a look on log at line states that ava.lang.IllegalStateException: Surface has already been released.  , please visit , hope it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665636/livewallpaper-java-lang-illegalstateexception-surface-has-already-been-release

Comment: thanks, i've already seen this question, but i don't think it's useful in my case. the dialog doesn't create any `AsyncTasks` and also isn't dismissed until the user presses a button (which he can't because the app crashes before the dialog is displayed) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we finally figured it out by ourselves, at least how we get it to work. the problem has been that we were still using the deprecated `showDialog()`-method instead of `DialogFragments`. It seems there are cases in which `showDialog()` and `AlertDialog.setView()` don't work together, in other cases they obviously do, we had another dialog which was still working. After introducing `DialogFragments` to our app the dialog starts just like in previous API-versions.